# Unable to find response container for <UUID>

Tags: liferay, cluster-computing, liferay-6

I see this error in a Liferay log file:

```
INFO  [Incoming-1,liferay-channel-control,FOO03-38099][ClusterRequestReceiver:250]
Unable to find response container for b62ef2ea-00c6-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b
```

When searching the Internet, there are only 7 results, mostly source code, plus 2 Liferay issues that seem to ignore the message.

My question:

- What does this message mean really?
- Can I safely ignore it?

Comment: `b62ef2ea-00c6-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b` this is not a portlet??

Comment: The uuid is not a portlet but an identification of the a Cluster Response object. The Response does not contain any results. Do you have any log messages from the other cluster nodes? When does this log Info occur? On Server Startup?

Comment: @AndreAlbert: It happens hundreds of time per day, always during daytime when there are people using Liferay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context you're describing doesn't contain a lot of hints as to when this is occuring. Due to the location of the code deep within clustering, it's quite abstract.

Based on the fact that

- it's not an ERROR but an INFO
- The comment on [LPS-56376](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-56376): "Has no real impact to system other than info level log messages stating: *Unable to find response container for:... from ClusterRequestReceiver*"
- The title of LPS-56376: "ClusterableAdvice is not flagging methods that return void as "fire and forget""

and without deeper analysis, I'd ignore this message.